# Integration of owncloud desktop client with dolphin

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, kubuntu, dolphin, owncloud-client

I have installed ownCloud desktop sync client in Kubuntu 18.04 and it works properly. In other words, when I add or delete files/directories in my ownCloud directory, the changes will also be reflected in the server and other devices. Now I am looking for this package that enables me to share files directly from Dolphin, without having to access the web interface. I have found a relevant question in the following link:

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/68zefx/dolphin_and_ownnextcloud/

However, I do not understand how to actually install such a package. Another [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/5h5x6i/how_do_you_remove_own_cloud_check_marks_from/) suggests that the package name is `owncloud-client-dolphin`. However, I could not find such a package. I could only find the following package that might be related:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/dolphin-owncloud

Unfortunately, I don't know how to install this package. Is there a simple way to install this package (if it is the right package to install) in Kubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04.1 the package for Dolphin is called 'dolphin-owncloud'.
To adress in Dolphin use webdav: 
'webdavs://yourOwncloudWebsite/remote.php/webdav/'.